# CS50 crack problem. Need help about how to decrypt 2-4 character words

Tags: c, string, encryption, cs50

I am new to programming that's why i start doing cs50. But i'm stuck on crack problem of pset2. As you probably know in CS 50 they give a hash of a word of maximum 4 alphabetical characters and you need to decrypt it. I have done with the decryption of 1 character hashes but i am stuck at decryption of 2 - 4 characters.

At the moment I know just the basics (stuff i studied in first 2 weeks on of cs50). I never worked with memory allocation and pointers.

My questions are 
1. Is it possible to solve this problem without using pointers? 
2. How should I pass e argument from my newly generated array (char_2 in this situation) to crypt function so the error don't appear preferably without using pointers.

MAybe you can help me with some tips about how to do this without using pointers (if this solution needs pointers).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
if(argc != 2)
{
    printf("Enter the hash code as a single argument\n");
    return 1;
}

string salt = get_string("Imput the salt\n");

string key[] = {
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Y", "Z", "a",
    "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "x", "y", "z"
};

char temp [40];
string hash = strcpy(temp, argv[1]);


    for(int i=0; i<18; i++)
    {
        string cypher = crypt(key[i], salt);

        int comp = strcmp(cypher, hash);

        if(comp == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", key[i]);
            break;
        }

    }
    char char_2[7500];
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            sprintf(char_2, "%s%s", key[i], key[j]);
            for(int m = 0; m < strlen(char_2); m++)
            {
                string cypher = crypt(char_2[m], salt);
                int comp = strcmp(cypher, hash);
                if(comp == 0)
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", key[i]);
                        break;
                    }
            }

        }


    }
```

The error I recive are the following:

```
crack3.c:69:47: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &
      [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
                        string cypher = crypt(char_3[m], salt);
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to solve next to **anything** in C without using pointers. Your `string` is actually a pointer already.

Comment: Read about the `crypt` function and what arguments it takes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it takes const chars. I created an array char_2 and than a for loop to take 1 character at a time from the array.

Comment: More precisely it takes *pointers* to a `const char`, i.e. `const char *`. In short, it takes as arguments two strings. And `char_2[m]` is a single `char`, not a pointer to one and as such is not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial approach for 2-character passwords is not so far from working, but the major mistake is that you try to pass individual password characters to `crypt()` (which cannot work) rather than the whole password candidate at once. Compare your code in the inner loop to this correction:

```
            sprintf(char_2, "%s%s", key[i], key[j]);
            // Don't loop over individual letters of password 'char_2' here!
            string cypher = crypt(char_2, salt);
            int comp = strcmp(cypher, hash);
            if (comp == 0)
            {
                printf("%s\n", char_2); // print the found password
                return;                 // no need to look further
            }
```

Of course you still have to add code for 3-, 4- and 5-character passwords.